# Add fact to list if it's not already in

Tags: list, prolog

I need to construct a list based on facts I have. For example I have a course list like this :

```
    attend(student1,c1).
    attend(student1,c2).
    attend(student2,c1).
    attend(student2,c3).
```

Now I want to have a predicate courselist/2 which returns a list of courses for a given student. Of course every course should be in this list only once. I can't use built-in predicates like findall but I can use member or append. So far I have something like this :

```
    courselist(S,R) :- attend(S,C), member(C,R), courselist(S,R).
    courselist(S,R) :- attend(S,C), append([C],L,R), courselist(S,R).
```

and I know that's wrong but I don't know how to find all facts without getting into an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's a silly restriction that you cannot use `findall/3`, because it is a natural solution for such a problem. You can do it manually like this:

```
student_courses(Student, Courses) :-
        student_courses(Student, [], Courses).

student_courses(S, Cs0, Cs) :-
        (   attend(S, C), \+ member(C, Cs0) ->
            student_courses(S, [C|Cs0], Cs)
        ;   Cs = Cs0
        ).
```

Example query:

```
?- student_courses(student2, Cs).
Cs = [c3, c1].
```

Note that this is not a true relation, since this particular solution does not appear in the following *more general* query:

```
?- student_courses(Student, Cs).
Student = student1,
Cs = [c2, c1].
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to implement it in such a way that the most general query yields *all* correct results. Also notice the more readable and relational predicate names.